# Solve for the two segments of the smaller triangle of two overlapping triangles with ratios of their segments and area.

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry

Triangle ▵ABC is provided.

Point X is along segment AC where |AX| : |XC| = 1 : x

and point Y is along segment BC where |BY| : |YC| = 1 : y.

Show all natural numbers x and y if the ratio of areas A▵ABC : A▵XYC = 2 : 1 is known.

(Solve this task without using Trigonometry.)

> I'm not sure if triangles ▵ABC and ▵XYC are supposed to be similar or not.
>
> I have an idea on how to solve this if they're similar.
>
> It'd be nice to see someone post a solution that consider these triangles not similar.

Comment: The triangles are similar (mainly only) when $ x = y $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $ \frac{x}{1+x} \frac{y}{1+y}  A\triangle ABC = A\triangle XYC$.

Hence, $ (x-1)(y-1) = 2 $ which only has solutions  $(2,3), (3,2)$.

Comment: Just clarifying if $\frac{x}{1+x} \frac{y}{1+y}  A\triangle ABC = A\triangle XYC$ is from $\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right) \left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)   = \frac{A\triangle XYC}{A\triangle ABC}$ which is derived from Area of Similar Triangles Theorem? So this applies if $\triangle XYC$ and $\triangle ABC$ are similar. I hope I'm following you correctly.

Comment: @laonlaan What you're using is just the ratio of side lengths. It can be derived in a similar manner as area of similar triangles, but  they are NOT similar.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by - similar manner as area of similar triangles, but they are not similar.

Comment: @laonlaan It was expressed in your (now-deleted) comment. The area of a triangle is given by $ \frac{1}{2} a b \sin C$, so if two triangles share a common angle, then the ratio of their areas is equal to the ratio of the product of the corresponding sides.

Comment: So you mean this $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) (x)(y) \sin θ}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) (1+x)(1+y) \sin θ} = \frac{A\triangle XYC}{A\triangle ABC}$ which can be simplified to $\frac{(x)(y)}{(1+x)(1+y)} = \frac{A\triangle XYC}{A\triangle ABC}$. Many thanks sir, but wouldn't this be using Trigonometry?

Comment: There are various ways of proving that statement without using trigonometry, esp if we're only changing one of the sides lengths at a time. For example, using 1/2*base*height, we can draw the conclusion about  x / (1+x).

Comment: I think I figured it out. If I get ratio of the areas of $A\triangle ACY$ and $A\triangle ABC$ - the result is $\frac{y}{1+y}$, since both triangles have same height. If I do the same with $A\triangle XYC$ and $A\triangle ACY$ - we get $\frac{x}{1+x}$. Then multiply $\left(\frac{A\triangle ACY}{A\triangle ABC}\right)\left(\frac{A\triangle XYC}{A\triangle ACY}\right)=\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$. Then simplify $\frac{A\triangle XYC}{A\triangle ABC}=\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$.